# when i try to run the updateOne method in mongoDB , i get this error uncaught exception: SyntaxError: illegal character :

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The Query:

```
db.products.updateOne(
      {"name":"pen"},
      {$set : { "stock" : 32}},
)
```

I got this error:

> uncaught exception: SyntaxError: illegal character :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `$set` with `"$set"`. Also, enter the code in the question instead of putting images.